# Change cell color based on who submitted the answers

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way wherein the submission answers of example Person A will change in red while Person B will change in blue using Google Appscript?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const color = {PersonAEmail:"#ff0000",PersonBEmail:"#0000ff"};
range.setFontColor(color[Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
```

[Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session)

[User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user)

Comment: Should the email be formatted like: const color = {name@email.com:"#ff0000",PersonBEmail:"#0000ff"};

Comment: I don't understand your question